# Can we show $\sigma_p(T)\setminus\sigma_p(T')=\sigma_r(T')$?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space and $T\in\mathfrak L(X)$.

> Can we show that $\sigma_p(T)\setminus\sigma_p(T')=\sigma_r(T')$?

I think the claim is true: Let $\lambda\in\mathbb C$. Then$^1$, $$\mathcal N(\lambda-T)=\mathcal R(\lambda-T')_\perp\tag1.$$ If $\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)$, then $$\overline{\mathcal R(\lambda-T')}\ne X'\tag2$$ by $(1)$. And if additionally $\lambda\not\in\sigma_p(T')$, then $\lambda\in\sigma_r(T')$ by $(2)$.

On the other hand, if $\lambda\in\sigma_r(T')$, then $\mathcal N(\lambda-T')=\{0\}$ (hence $\lambda\not\in\sigma_p(T')$) and it holds $(2)$, which should yield $$\mathcal N(\lambda-T)\ne\{0\}\tag3$$ by $(1)$ (hence $\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)$).

> Right?

---

$^1$ If $V\subseteq X'$, then $$V_\perp:=\{x\in X:\langle x,\varphi\rangle=0\text{ for all }\varphi\in V\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, (2) does not imply (3) in general.

The implication ``$\overline{ R(\lambda-T')} \ne X'$ $\Rightarrow$ $N(\lambda-T)\ne\{0\}$'' is true for reflexive Banach space $X$ (invoke Hahn-Banach in $X'$, represent the so-obtained functional in $X''$ by an element in $X$). It is not true non-reflexive Banach spaces:

Take $X=c_0$, $X'=l_1$, $T=I-L$, $T'=I-R$, where $L$ and $R$ are left and right shift. Then
$$
R(T') \subset \{ x\in l^1: \ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=0\},
$$
where the set on the right is a closed, proper subspace of $X'$, but $N(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But do you agree that the other direction is correct?

Comment: yes, the first part / first inclusion is correct.

Comment: Thanks for verifying. What I've got in mind, by the way, was the left shift $L:\ell^p\to\ell^p$ and its adjoint, the right shift $R:\ell^q\to\ell^q$, where $1\le p<q\le\infty$. $L$ has operator norm $1$ and $R$ is even an isometry. It's easy to see that $σ_p(L)=B_1(0)$ and hence $σ(L)=\overline B_1(0)$. Moreover, $σ_p(R)=\emptyset$ and $σ(R)=σ(L')=σ(L)=\overline B_1(0)$. By the first part of this question, $B_1(0)=σ_p(L)\setminusσ_p(R)\subseteqσ_r(L')=σ_r(R)$. But I'm not able to conclude that this is actually an equality and $σ_c(R)=\emptyset$. Any idea?